# Apply image perspective through batch mode in gimp

Tags: images, gimp

I need to perform image perspective operation from command line?

Is there any place where documentation is provided properly. I have asked this question on stack overflow, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23652196/apply-image-perspective-feature-through-gimp-batch-mode?noredirect=1#comment36328141_23652196).

If any other tool is available which provides command line interface to do same thing then it will also good for me.

Comment: What are perspective operations?

Comment: @slm http://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-tool-perspective.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best tool for manipulating images would be ImageMagick. If you take a look at the documentation there are extensive examples that show how to use the `-distort` feature which I believe is what you're looking for.

- http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/

#### Example

Before
            [image: ss #1]                  After      [image]

Command line to perform the conversion:

```
$ convert checks.png -filter point           
    -virtual-pixel tile -mattecolor DodgerBlue
    -distort Perspective '0,0 20,60  90,0 70,63  0,90 5,83  90,90 85,88'
    horizon_tile_point.png
```

There are 2 other methods for doing the sampling to get the resulting image looking better. Specifically "Grid Super Sampling" & "Elliptical Weighted Area
(EWA) Resampling". The latter is the default.

#### How do I calculate the coordinates?

There are 2 resources for getting a grasp of how to generate the series of coordinates to `convert`. The first is the one I gave above. The second is this SO Q&A titled: [Understanding Perspective Projection Distortion ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276098/understanding-perspective-projection-distortion-imagemagick), specifically [@KurtPfeifle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12278644/33204).

The coordinates are as follows:

```
Sx1,Sy1 Dx1,Dy1   Sx2,Sy2 Dx2,Dy2   Sx3,Sy3 Dx3,Dy3   ...   Sxn,Syn Dxn,Dyn
```

- x is used to represent an X coordinate.
- y is used to represent an Y coordinate.
- 1, 2, 3, ... n is used to represent the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, ... nth pixel.
- S is used here for the source pixel.
- D is used here for the destination pixel.

#### References

- [Distort options page 1 using ImageMagick](http://www.rubblewebs.co.uk/imagemagick/operators/distort.php)

Comment: I have gone through similar kind of process i guess, need one more help. can you tell the place of wiki where position of 16 points we are giving is specified. Its not on main site, I am using **Imagick** class' **distortImage()**

Comment: @mastkalandar - see updates. Take a look at the SO Q&A I linked, it has everything you need to understand the coordinates.